# Hiding elements?

Tags: php, jquery, element

I want to hide 2 div-s but instead of hiding those 2 div-s, jquery and PHP are hiding the whole site except the body.

Here is my code

```
<script>
    function SokrijNajavaKopce(){
        $("#najavakopce").hide();
        $("#najavakopceotvoreno").hide();
    }
</script>

<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']))
    {   
        SokrijNajavaKopce();
    }
?>
```

And whole site is hiding ??

Comment: You can not call a `JavaScript` function from `PHP`. You can instead use `PHP` to echo a JavaScript call to that function.

Comment: Oh, God, You cant use a client-side function in server-side. To be clear, You can not use a javascript function, which is here client-side in php which is server-side

Comment: where is your html code? Post it plz.

Comment: I would guess what's really happening is that PHP is crashing, because that function doesn't exist in PHP, and because error reporting is switched off you are seeing a blank screen. Enable error reporting (you can google how to do it) and you'll see the real problem. As others have said, you can't mix PHP and JavaScript together like that. If you want to hide the two divs when the page is first loaded then either set their CSS style to `display:none` in the initial markup, or call your JavaScript function from within the JavaScript section

Answer (score 2):

You're calling javascript in php context. PHP is bugging out.  Output it like below...

```
<script>
    function SokrijNajavaKopce(){
        $("#najavakopce").hide();
        $("#najavakopceotvoreno").hide();
    }
</script>

<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']))
    {   
        echo "<script>SokrijNajavaKopce();</script>";
    }
?>
```